# SQLite database Upgrade Schema without loosing data

Tags: sqlite, c#

I have a small C# Windows Forms application.
It uses SQLite DB on the client's PC.
I started with a Schema DB and with time I added more tables and columns to my local DB (not the client's).

I want to upgrade the client's DB Schema without losing data.
So far I could update the schema but some information is lost because of drop tables and recreating them.

Can anyone help me?

This is an example of 2 tables. I just add new columns.
No easy diagram generator for SQLite.
Add **** for added columns

**Table Usuarios**  CLIENT

```
UserId           Integer                   
NombreUsuario    TEXT                      
Password         TEXT                      
ProfesionID      Integer    
Mail             TEXT
```

**Table Usuarios NEW VERSION**

```
UserId           Integer   
NombreUsuario    TEXT    
Password         TEXT     
ProfesionID      Integer   
Mail             TEXT    
UseImages        Integer  ****  
Color            Integer  ****  
BackUpDate       TEXT     ****
```

**Table EquiposHabilitados CLIENT**

```
EquipoID       TEXT
```

**Table EquiposHabilitados   NEW VERSION**

```
Equipo                   TEXT    ****     
EquipoID                 TEXT       
EquipoFechaVencimiento   TEXT    ****     
UltimoTiempo             TEXT    ****
```

Comment: Please add your Table definitions for both the client's instance and your local version, some example data, and the changes you're trying to release to the client's instance. Answers will vary depending on exactly what kind of schema changes you're trying to make.

Comment: Is better now? Or should I generate the Diagram?

Comment: In your `EquiposHabilitados` table, you changed the column order by adding the new column `Equipo` **before** the `EquipoID`. Is it acceptable for you to design it instead to add `Equipo` **after** `EquipoID`?...This would simplify the solution, and generally you shouldn't care about column order in Tables too much.

Comment: I'm OK with not changing order. This was a one time change. I will never change positions again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd alter existing tables when adding new columns but I read there are some concerns to considerate when altering tables, check https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Focus in the `7. Making Other Kinds Of Table Schema Changes` section, in the square of correct and incorrect steps to drop/re-create a table